# Função em Go com parametros no lugar do nome?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, stack, golang

Olá, gostaria entender como funcionam as funções na linguagem Go, fiz um codigo para montar a estrutura de dados Pilha e me deparei com duas funções que no lugar do nome possui um parenteses com parametros e logo em seguida o nome com outro parenteses e seu parametro, obrigado!

Segue o codigo:

```
type Stack struct {
    items []int
}

func (s *Stack) Push(i int) {
    s.items = append(s.items, i)
}

func (s *Stack) Pop() int {
    l := len(s.items) - 1
    toRemove := s.items[l]
    s.items = s.items[:l]

    return toRemove
}
```

Comment: Qual a duvida, especificamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta está um pouco confusa, mas acho que consegui entender. A sua duvida parece consistir em:

```
type AlgumTipo struct {
}

func (t *AlgumTipo) UmaFuncao(argumento int) {
}
```

A função `UmaFuncao` parece ser o que descreve como "funções que no lugar do nome possui um parenteses com parametros e logo em seguida o nome com outro parenteses e seu parametro".

---

Infelizmente, não sei se vou conseguir explicar.

---

O que acontece é que você pode implementar funções diretamente no seu tipo (que pode ser tanto struct, quanto qualquer outra coisa).

Considere os dois códigos:

```
type Cliente struct {
    Username string
}

func (c *Cliente) Name(titulo string) string {
    return titulo + c.Username
}
```

Você também poderia escrever como:

```
type Cliente struct {
    Username string
}

func Name(c *Cliente, titulo string) string {
    return titulo + c.Username
}
```

---

Então, você poderia utilizar (no primeiro caso):

```
cliente := Client{Username:"Bob"}
fmt.Println(cliente.Name("Senhor, "))

// Resultado: Senhor, Bob
```

---

Traduzindo o `func (c *Cliente) Name(titulo string) string`:

O `(c *Cliente)` define o nome de `c` para o struct de Cliente. Permitindo acessar os dados do `type Cliente struct{}`.

O `Name()` é o nome da função.

O `titulo string` é os argumentos/parâmetros de entrada para função. Assim, definindo o nome de `titulo` para a variavel que vai receber (o `string` é o tipo).

O `string` ao final é o tipo do resultado da função.

---

O `(c *Cliente)` está obtendo a informação do struct do `Cliente`, ou seja ele implementa o tipo `Cliente`. Como eu criei um struct com o nome "Bob", ao chamar o `Name(...)` ele leu esta informação (usando o `c.Username`). Além disso, como ele usa o `*Cliente` ele também é capaz de modificar o conteúdo do struct.

Como no seu caso, ao utilizar:

```
func (s *Stack) Push(i int) {
    s.items = append(s.items, i)
}
```

Você define o `items` do `Stack` atual.

> Note: tenha cuidado com acessos paralelos/concorrentes, caso duas funções altere a mesma variável ao mesmo tempo o programa pode, literalmente, crashar! *Você pode usar o `sync.Mutex` e afins para previnir isso, mas isso é outro assunto.*

---

Uma pergunta que talvez tenha é: porque usar `(c *Cliente) Name(titulo string) string` ao invés de criar um `Name(c *cliente, titulo string) string`? Entre outros fatores, o principal deles é o uso de Interface.

Você pode criar uma `Interface` como:

```
type Namer interface {
    Name(prefix string) string
}
```

Dessa forma, qualquer coisa que implementar tal função será um `Namer`.

Isso é bastante útil em algumas situações. Como por exemplo o `io.Reader`, o `io.Reader` é uma interface (https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader):

```
type Reader interface {
    Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

Ou seja, POR EXEMPLO (*mas não use isso*), caso você faça um:

```
func (c *Cliente) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n = copy(p, []byte(c.Username))
    return n, io.EOF
}
```

Você terá implementado o `io.Reader` no `type Cliente struct{}`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, entendi perfeitamente!!